# Excel: Select every 5th column on another sheet, drag and autofill

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm looking to select every 5th column from another sheet, and put it into one row where they're next to each other, and be able to drag it so it autofills as there is a lot more columns.

It should come out like:

```
=Sheet1!B$4 | =Sheet1!G$4 | =Sheet1!L$4 | =Sheet1!Q$4 ...
=Sheet1!C$4 | =Sheet1!H$4 | =Sheet1!M$4 | =Sheet1!R$4 ...
...
```

How can I do this with a formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first cell of choice:

`=INDEX(Sheet1!$4:$4,5*(COLUMNS($A:A)-1)+ROWS($1:2))`

Copy across and down as required.

Note that `INDEX` set-ups should be preferred to volatile `OFFSET`/`INDIRECT` ones.

Regards